# PyTorch training loss is 0.00 and validation Accuracy is 1.00 from first epoch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, neural-network, data-preprocessing

Hi I am trying to train a model. but I keep getting an accuracy of 1 on my test dataset right from the first epoch. In my dataset I mostly have negative cases. (i.e. most targets are zero. Only 35 of 300k is positive).

Here is the Model.

```
class LoanModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(LoanModel, self).__init__()

        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(12, 20)
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(20, 20)
        self.linear3 = torch.nn.Linear(20, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        # print(f"After linear1 {x}")
        x = self.activation(x)        
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.linear3(x)
        # print(f"After linear3 {x}")
        # print(f"Before sigmoid {x}")
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x 
      
loan_model = LoanModel()
```

Here is the optimiser and criterion.

```
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(loan_model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
```

This is my dataLoader.

```
train_df, val_df = df_clean[:200000], df_clean[200000:]

# Convert the DataFrames to PyTorch tensors
train_X = torch.tensor(train_df.drop(['target'], axis=1).values).float()
train_y = torch.tensor(train_df['target'].values).float()
val_X = torch.tensor(val_df.drop(['target'], axis=1).values).float()
val_y = torch.tensor(val_df['target'].values).float()

# Create PyTorch DataLoaders
train_data = data_utils.TensorDataset(train_X, train_y)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32)
val_data = data_utils.TensorDataset(val_X, val_y)
val_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=32)
```

This is my trainer

```
num_epochs = 10

# Train the model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Set the model to train mode
    loan_model.train()
    
    # Loop over the batches in the training data
    for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # targets = targets.view(-1, 1)
        outputs = loan_model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        # print(f"Output is {outputs} and inputs are {inputs}")
    
    # Evaluate the model on the validation data
    loan_model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    val_acc = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, targets in val_loader:
            # inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)
            outputs = loan_model(inputs)
            val_loss += criterion(outputs, targets.long())
            val_acc += (outputs.argmax(1) == targets).sum().item()
    val_loss /= len(val_loader)
    val_acc /= len(val_loader.dataset)
    
    # Print the epoch number, training loss, and validation loss and accuracy
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Train Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {val_acc:.4f}')
```

The issue is I am getting no change in accuracy. Neither decreases and wont increase of course.

This is the output I get.

```
Epoch [1/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [2/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [3/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [4/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [5/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [6/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [7/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [8/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [9/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
Epoch [10/10], Train Loss: 0.0000, Val Loss: 0.0000, Val Acc: 1.0000
```

I don't know how to proceed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much

I tried changing the criterion and the model itself. but nothing workerd.

Comment: Can you give an example of your input data ?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a highly imbalanced class.
I think the fraction of 0 labels is almost 1, so the model will always predict 0.

Another thing is how you measure your loss. You can use weighted loss so it weights the loss per class label.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with classification but you're using torch.nn.MSELoss() which is for regression